# Append to all dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list `all`. There are many dictionaries in it. I have to append a key value `datetime` to all of them.

Here is my method:

```
all = [{'name': "sadness", 'class': 'A1'},
       {'name': 'joy',     'class': 'B1'},
       {'name': 'mark',    'class': 'C1'}]

import datetime

for d in all:
    d['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now()

print all
```

Is there another method more fast to do this??

Comment: Careful `all` is a built in function.

Comment: You are appending different values to dictionary as current datetime changes. Maybe you should declare `current_date = datetime.datetime.now()` before loop and use `d['datetime'] = current_date` then

Comment: There's unlikely to be a faster method. If there was any more syntactically concise expression it would still need to do the same work.

Comment: @AChampion, oh, but there is. See my answer

Comment: Note the majority of the time is wasted on the repeated calls to `now()`. See the timings in my anser. Even if you avoid that, there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent time across all dictionaries use

```
a = [{'name':"sadness",'calss':'A1'},{'name':'joy','class':'B1'},{'name':'mark','class':'C1'}]
import datetime
c={'datetime':datetime.datetime.now()}
for d in a:
    d.update(c)
print a
```

Comment: `c = datetime.datetime.now()` and `d['datetime'] = c` is significantly faster than calling `update()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your data seems tabular in nature, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all)
df['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now()
print df
```

If you choose to leave it as a list of dicts, I'm affraid your loop is the only way to achieve that.

Also, `all` is not a good variable name in python.

---

**Timings**

For a big list of 1M elements, assuming you store your data in a dataframe to begin with, this is faster by a factor of 8!

```
N = 1000000
all = [ {'a': 'a%s'%i, 'b':i} for i in range(N) ]
df = pd.DataFrame(all)

%timeit df['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.38 ms per loop
%timeit for d in all: d['datetime'] = now
10 loops, best of 3: 46.7 ms per loop
```

Or, with repeated calls to now():

```
%timeit for d in all: d['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now()
1 loops, best of 3: 597 ms per loop
```

Comment: @AChampion, assuming the data is stored in a DataFrame to begin with (i.e. no conversion is needed), which is a natural choice for this kind of tabular data, the aproach in this answer is massively faster.

Comment: It's all where you measure from - OP wasn't using pandas and the result isn't in the format the OP asked for. Other than that - agree it can be faster.